# How to debug indexed data by thinking sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm new with sphinx and I'd like to see what's in `technology_core` because my query is not returning what should be. Actually is not even querying in the db those two results.

```
Processing by TechnologiesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>{"tech_type"=>["1"], "area_of_interest"=>["4"]}, "query"=>"", "_"=>"1417734808773"}
  Sphinx Query (1.4ms)  SELECT *, groupby() AS sphinx_internal_group, id AS sphinx_document_id, count(DISTINCT sphinx_document_id) AS sphinx_internal_count FROM `technology_core` WHERE `tag_id` IN (1, 4) AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 GROUP BY `technology_id` HAVING COUNT(*)=2 LIMIT 0, 20
  Sphinx  Found 2 results
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered technologies/index.js.erb (2.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I though data were stored into a new db table but there's no a `technology_core` table created. Then I remembered there's a `db/sphinx` folder, so I guess the indexed data must be stored in there.
Is there a way to query that `technology_core` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to Sphinx via the `mysql` command-line tool:

```
mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9306
```

And then run SphinxQL queries (which is similar but not the same as SQL - the `Sphinx Query` line in your log is a SphinxQL query). The [Sphinx docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-reference) cover the syntax pretty well.

It's worth keeping in mind that SphinxQL queries will return all attribute values (well, unless you only request some attributes in your SELECT clause), but they will not return fields.